# CoreLocation Swift Terminated due to signal 9 in Background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cpu, core-location

I have a mysterious problem right here !

I make an app using CoreLocation and TCP connection to sending my position.
In foreground mode I have no problem, however in background it's an other deal !

While I move with my phone in background mode, core location work. But when I'm stop, after few second or a minute my app kill with "Terminated due to signal 9"

So this message explain in my log iPhone that is a security CPU from iOS ... OK so the problem is in this line I supposed

```
.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically
.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates
```

But after many try I always have the same error in background mode and without moving with the expected message "Terminated due to signal 9"...

Some one can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had the same problem on iOS 14, solution was to add "push notifications" to the requested capabilities (Xcode 12)